# Error:A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client-- Allowing JavaScript to be submitted

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

We have a site were trusted users can add some Javascript tracking code into a text box for submitting, so naturally **we have turned off Validation by adding the ValidateRequest="false"** into the Page Directive.

However it we seem to be getting the error again all of a sudden : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client , Now **we cant add ValidateRequest="false" into the Config or the Master page** this page inherits from. So how do I allow Javascript to be posted, what is overridding the ValidateRequest?

We are using .Net 3.5

Comment: once you add validaterequest=false to a page you will not get the error on that page. maybe your code is redirecting to another page after submit and that page is throwing this error. Kindly check.

Comment: Probably didn't understand it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something else, not the Page, is triggering the error due to the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) made in the framework.. if you can't edit the `web.config` I fear you're pretty much stuck.

Comment: I just noticed this site was actually running in 4.0 and this was the problem.